# QuickBooks Enterprise Freezing/Crashing (have tried almost everything at this point...)

Tags: freeze, quickbooks

A few weeks ago an end-user that runs QB Enterprise v23 (Manufacturing and Wholesale) on her computer (which also serves as the QB server for three other workstations) reported that while leaving QB running but minimized throughout the day, it would just randomly shut down (and disappear from the taskbar) with no warning. At the time, she was running Win10 Pro.

In looking at the Windows event viewer, I came across the following entries:

> Event ID: 4
>
> An unexpected error has occured in "Intuit QuickBooks Enterprise
> Solutions: Manufacturing and Wholesale 23.0":
>
> LTSM:: Failure in parsing EWS Response. PSID=

> Event ID: 4
>
> An unexpected error has occured in "QuickBooks":
>
> MainFrame must be already created by now as this dll is demand loaded

I tried a bunch of troubleshooting based on the above errors, including full reinstallation of QuickBooks, but nothing solved the issue. I got Intuit Support involved (at an escalated level since I couldn't actually get anyone at a regular level to even assist/respond) and they took a look at the QB logs themselves and provided some suggestions (I can't recall all) that did not help. Here are those suggestions that I can remember (that did not help):

- Turning off Auto Data Recovery (ADR)
- Running a local verification and repair of the QB company file

Around this time, the end-user reported that now QB was just randomly freezing throughout the day and the only way to close it and regain access was to kill the application via task manager. Another user had previously reported the same silent crashes that this end-user was previously experiencing, but this other user now reported no further issues on their end (they were one of the other workstations that just accessed the QB company file over the network).

The QB company file was provided to Intuit Support's Data Department and they supposedly made some fixes, but on using the "fixed" copy the problem persisted. I upgraded the end-user to Win11 on the off chance that this might help, but it did not. Finally, I backed everything up, did a full wipe and reinstall of the OS (via cloud download of Win11) and then reinstalled everything...and the problem STILL was occurring.

I'm pretty much out of ideas at this point. I can try moving the QB company file elsewhere on the network, but I don't think that will help. The only other "solutions" I can come up with are to have the end-user access QB via remote access internally (using VNC or similar) on another computer, or maybe just moving them to cloud hosting (not QuickBooks Online, but true cloud hosting of QB).

If anyone has any other suggestions, I'd definitely be grateful!

P.S. The only thing I can think of is that maybe some of the software I reinstalled is somehow conflicting with QB all-of-a-sudden (most software has been on this computer for a while, but maybe an update to another piece of software is causing issues?). Here's a screenshot of all the software installed if it helps: https://ibb.co/pvTK0VY

P.P.S. One other thing that these end-users have a habit of doing is leaving QB running after they are done for the day. I've told them countless times not to do that, but they do it anyway. I don't think that has any bearing on this issue (since they have been doing it for a lot longer than this issue has been occurring), but just thought I'd mention it.